# Shrink a banach space to a closed linear span of an into isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, isometry

[Theorem $2.2$](https://lmb.univ-fcomte.fr/IMG/pdf/coursLens2010.pdf) states that

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be separable Banach spaces and suppose that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is an into isometry, then $X$ is linearly isometric to a subspace of $Y$.

In the proof, the author mentioned that

> We may assume that $Y$ is equal to the closed linear span of $f(X)$.

Question: Why can we assume that?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is isometric to a subspace of $\overline{f(X)}$, then of course it is isometric to a subspace of $Y$.  So, we might as well assume $\overline{f(X)}=Y$.

Comment: Then why involves closed linear span?

Comment: This answer is not complete (hence, not a Banach answer). You should note that $f(X)$ is neither a linear space (hence, you need the span) nor complete (hence, the closure).

Comment: Oops, I left out the overline.  But yes, there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z$ be the closed linear span of $f(X)$. Then, (due to the closure!) $Z$ is again a Banach space and $X$ is linearly isomorphic to a subspace of $Z$ iff it is linearly isomorphic to a subspacef of $Y$.